# Add cookie that lasts as long as browser is open

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Hi    I have an age verification when you visit my site. When you are old enough you get through the age verification but the problem is, that everytime you turn to that page again, the age verification is showed again - and it should. The user shouldn't have to go through the age verification again, until the browser is closed.    Can anyone help me with that? I have this javascript if and the cookie should be added within that.

```
if(age > 18){
COOKIE HERE
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into session variables in this case.

Comment: If you don't specify the expiry-date for the cookie, it will become a session-cookie. Google it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's no duration on the cookie, the default behaviour is to delete it when the browser exits. Check the example.

```
if(age > 18){
    document.cookie="unrestricted=true"; 
} //This is to set the cookie after some sort of "promise" from the user that they are over 18
```

You can then check if the cookie has been set.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("unrestricted=true;") >= 0) {
   alert("Unrestricted access");
}
```

For more complete tutorials on cookies check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 4):

If you dont specify expire value when setting cookie the cookie will automatically delete on browser close eg.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: It does, thanks! But how do I check, if there is a cookie then? It needs to check for the cookie first, and if it is found the age verification should not show at all :-)

Comment: Or how do I get the cookie, so I can check if it is blank or something like that?

Comment: You can check it using if(isset($_COOKIE["TestCookie"])) {}

Comment: I have looked at that page already, but I cannot get it to work with my javascript.    When the if is correct: (if (age > 18)) then it should set a cookie. When visiting the page again, the cookie should make sure that you do not have to type your age again.

Comment: I think the OP needs JavaScript to set the cookies. Not sure why this was tagged with PHP though.